# Tkinter: ttk.Label displaying nothing when given StringVar as textvariable, inside a class

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I am trying to use the `textvariable` attribute of `ttk.Label` to display & update text according to a given `StringVar`.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class RenderEvent():
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.frame = ttk.Frame(self.root, padding="20 20 20 20")
        self.frame.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
        
        self.dialogue = StringVar(self.frame, value="Placeholder")
        L = ttk.Label(self.frame, textvariable=self.dialogue)
        L.grid(column=1, row=2, sticky=W)
        self.dialogue.set("some text here")
```

And for reference, `root` is passed in from another file which looks like this, and is used to start the application:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from renderevent import RenderEvent

root = Tk()
RenderEvent(root)
root.mainloop()
```

If I use `text` instead of `textvariable` in the Label creation, it displays a static string just fine. However, once it is set to `textvariable` (as shown above), nothing will be displayed at all.

I have tried the same with giving the StringVar() no parameters at all in initialization, or passing in `self.root`.

Emulating this code outside of a class seems to work as intended (the text appears and updates along with the `textvariable`), but I can't think of why having a class would cause an issue like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that you aren't keeping a reference to the instance of `RenderEvent`. Since you don't save a reference, python's garbage collector will try to clean it up which causes the variable to be cleaned up as well. The ttk widgets are more sensitive to this than the normal tk widgets.

The simple and arguably best solution is to assign the result of `RenderEvent(root)` to a variable so that it isn't affected by python's memory management.

```
re = RenderEvent(root)
```

Comment: They're just going to be back when they can't figure out how to style anything that they made. The easiest solution is to stop using ttk. All they have to do is delete 3 letters and a dot, and the code works. Your solution solves their problem, but will create many, many more.

Comment: @OneMadGypsy: _"They're just going to be back when they can't figure out how to style anything that they made. "_ - you have no way of knowing that. I think you're being overly negative and discouraging.  This solution creates literally zero problems.